# If I change a WSDL's targetNamespace, will it break existing consumers?

Tags: soap, wsdl, soa

I'm currently working on a SOA versioning strategy for my organization. I'm trying to determine where we should store the version number (Major.Minor) in the WSDL. There will be non-breaking changes made to the service interface (i.e. adding new operations) and for these non-breaking changes we'll just increment the minor number. We are considering using the WSDL's targetNamespace to store the version but we're afraid changing the WSDL's targetNamespace from something like 1.0 to 1.1 might result in a breaking change for some clients.

Can anyone tell me the effects that changing the targetNamespace of a WSDL will have on existing consumers of that particular web service.  I've run some tests using WCF and I've found that it doesn't break existing applications that use the service.  However, I'm wondering if this will still be true from other non-.NET clients?

Note: I do realize that changing the targetNamespace of a XSD referenced by the WSDL does result in a breaking change.

Comment: Yes, it will. Two elements with the same name but different namespaces are different elements.

Comment: Not sure I understand your response. Are you saying this may break some existing consumers?  What are the two elements you're referring to? I was suggesting changing the targetNamespace of an existing WSDL endpoint, not creating a new one.

Comment: I meant any two elements defined in the WSDL. For instance, if you change the `targetNamespace` of the WSDL, you're changing the namespace of the messages, bindings, portTypes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the Major version number in the namespace. Put the major and minor in a documentation element. There is a great book from Thomas Erl that covers this sort of stuff: [Web Service Contract Design and Versioning for SOA](http://www.soabooks.com/wsc/). The best thing about the book is that it will make you think about things you probably haven't considered, like if you plan/want to use a strict, backward compatible or forward compatible versioning strategy and what the implications of each are.